# ImageMagick из-за чего могут испортиться изображения?

Tags: java, debian, tomcat, изображения, imagemagick

Всем привет! На то, почему у меня периодически портятся картинки на сервере я не смог найти ответа. Периодически, значит что фото не сразу портится, а через некоторое время. И происходит это не так уж редко.

Команда для обработки оригинала:

```
convert "$1" -resize "680x>" "middle_"$2
```

В итоге, получаются нормальное изображение, а через не определенное время может испортиться, как вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сервер на Debian 6 Squeeze 64 bit

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.6.0-4 2015-11-27 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

Каковы возможные причины таких последствий?

Еще важное замечание. Больше года код на сайте не менял сервер не перезапускал, только файлы добавлял. Не разу такой проблемы не всплывало.

Буквально недавно снова начал вносить изменения в код, перезапускать исключительно Tomcat 8, еще менял sh файл который обрезает фото (разрешал для выполнения как программу, т.к лежит в ROOT.war и при передеплое приложения у него сбрасывается это привилегия).

Еще директория с фотками находится в одной папке вместе с ROOT.war (может Tomcat как то влияет пагубно на фотки?).
Бесовщина какая то.

Comment: Контрольная сумма файла тоже меняется через некоторое время?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian скорее всего, сейчас прjверил два файла:
7BDD02F4FA28F47C59555B20CA8B0910 - не битая, 
4C3F164CC39FBD3ECCED3D802C9F54DA - битая

Comment: Тогда стоит помониторить обращения к файлу, посмотреть, кто его меняет.

Comment: Возможно аппаратная проблема

Comment: @sercxjo хостеру писал они тоже не в курсе, с диском все в порядке. Установил loggedfs, как VladimirGamalian советовал, пока тишина

Comment: Ответ хостера: "Сам по себе характер повреждения файлов наводит на мысль, что проблема может проявляться при обработке большого числа файлов и, к примеру, превышении доступной оперативной памяти." Памяти 16гб, а файлов последовательно запущенных через цикл на обработку не более 10 шт.

Comment: Недостаток оперативной памяти может привести к незапуску процесса или нулевому указателю в malloc, что может привести к прерыванию процесса, и в результате к полной потере  записываемого файла, но вряд ли приведёт к порче файла. В крайнем случае может сократиться длина, если oomkiller решит прибить процесс. Помониторьте процессы и память, посмотрите логи на сообщения "killed".

Comment: Как бы глупо/маловероятно это ни звучало, но пробегитесь антивирусом по испорченным файлам. У меня было подобное только в случае инъекций.